# you have no eligible Bundle IDs for iOS apps

Tags: ios, app-store

I have recently added one account to my Apple ID.so,now I have two accounts linked to one apple ID. I am able to add apps through my previous account.But now,I am trying to register app through the recently added account, it shows me `you have no eligible Bundle IDs for iOS apps` error even if I have valid bundle id and provisional profile.
I am stuck with this issue and not able to resolve.
Any help is appreciated to resolve my issue at earliest possible.

Answer (score 2):

1) Check bundle id, is it match with your certificate and profile.

2) Add proper account in Xcode->Preferences->Account.

3) After that download proper certificate and profile by clicking on ViewDetails.

4) If you have multiple account/team then select proper team while creating build from Info section in Xcode.

5) Select certificate and profile from build settings.

Here is the images for the same.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On the general screen for your project you can select the team. Do you have the correct team selected? Also, have you created the bundle ID on the Apple developer site using your new account?

Comment: Yes I have created bundle ID on the Apple developer site using new account , but before even selecting team I should be able to add new app in my apps section in iTunes account.i am not even able to add a app